# Why does the automorphism used to construct the group have to be non-inner?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I have a question on why a particular assumption is made that the automorphism used to construct a certain group be non-inner.

In [Herstein, Topics in Algebra, p. 69], a construction of a nonabelian group of order 21 is given as follows:  Let $G=C_7 = \langle a \rangle$, $\phi: a \mapsto a^2$ be an automorphism of $G$ of order 3, and consider all formal symbols $x^i a^j$ subject to conditions $x^3=a^7=e, x^{-1}ax=a^2$, and we get a nonabelian group of order 21.

The text continues that, more generally, if $G$ is a group, $T$ an automorphism of order $r$ of $G$ which is not an inner automorphism, pick a symbol $x$ and consider all elements $x^i g$, $i \in \mathbb{Z}, g \in G$, subject to $x^ig=x^{i'}g'$ iff $i \equiv i'(r), g =g'$, and $x^{-1} g^i x = gT^i$ for all $i$.  Then, we obtain a larger group $\{G,T\}$, with $G \trianglelefteq \{G,T\}, \{G,T\}/G \cong C_r$.  I think it is common to denote this group by the semidirect product $G \rtimes C_r$.  My question here is why is the assumption made that $T$ is ``not an inner automorphism.''

Comment: Probably he is in the context of abelian groups, I mean, given an abelian group $G$ we want to construct non-abelian groups from $G$.

Comment: Typically, if $T$ is an inner automorphism, then the result will just be the direct product $G\times C_r$.  More specifically, if $T$ is an inner automorphism of order $r$, and $T$ can be represented by conjugation by an element of $G$ of order $r$ (not guaranteed since $G$ my have nontrivial center), then the resulting group is just $G\times C_r$.

Comment: @Jim: If $G\rtimes \langle T\rangle=G\times\langle T\rangle$ then for any $g\in G$, $x=gxg^{-1}=xx^{-1}gxg^{-1}=x(gT)g^{-1}$ (I am using his notation) and therefore $gT=g$, that is, $T$ is the identity.

Comment: @Diego Sorry for the cryptic comment.  It's $G\times C_r$, but it isn't $G\times \langle x\rangle$.  If $T$ acts as conjugation by $h$ and has the same order as $h$, then $G\rtimes \langle x\rangle = G \times \langle h^{-1}x\rangle \cong G \times C_r$.

Comment: @JimBelk: that is a good answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inner automorphisms are bijective homomorphisms $\theta_g:G\rightarrow G$ which have the form $$\theta_g(x)=g^{-1}xg$$
given a fixed $g\in G$.  If $G$ is abelian, then $xg=gx$ for every $x,g\in G$, which we can rewrite as as $g^{-1}xg=x$.  Thus every inner automorphism has the form $$\theta_g(x)=x\hspace{30pt}\text{for all }x\in G.$$
In other words, all inner automorphisms are the identity automorphism $\operatorname{id}_G$.  If one forms a semidirect product $G\rtimes_\phi H$ with the mapping $\phi(h)=\operatorname{id}$ for every $h\in H$, then $$G\rtimes_\phi H\cong G\times H.$$
In the context of semidirect products, this is a degenerate case.  To see a "non-trivial semidirect product," $\phi$ must map at least one $h$ to a non-identity automorphism of $G$, and thus when $G$ is abelian this automorphism cannot be inner.